# Jquery: On form submit validate then allow default operation to continue

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

Wondering, is there a way to make a form execute default operation after preventingDefault and validating form fields.

```
$('#form').submit(function (e) { 
   e.preventDefault();
   var isValid = true;
   var name   = $('#name').val();

   if (empty(name)) {
     isValid = false;
   }

   $(this).submit() // This will cause a stack overflow :)

});
```

After I complete the form validation I want to proceed as normal,

I thought of using `onClick` on the submit button, but users can trigger submit by hitting on the enter key, which I want to allow. Reason why I want to do this is so that the server can perform its operations like redirecting.

Comment: _"After I complete the form validation I want to proceed as normal"_ - well there's your answer ... just prevent the event default at the end - or not -  after you did your validation checks ...

Comment: Try using `$('#form').on('submit',function(e){e.preventDefault();//validation $('#form').submit();})`

Comment: You should check name value so it should be $('#name').val()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `preventDefault`, you can `return true` at the end of the function.

If you want to prevent the submission, you can `return false`.

Here's an example using your code. If you try to submit the form with an empty field, it won't submit. If you fill the field, it will:

```js
$("#form").submit(function() {
  var name = $("#name").val();

  if (!name) {
    $(".form-group").addClass("has-danger");
    alert("Field is blank. Submit will be prevented.");
    return false; // no submission
  }

  alert("Field is filled. The form will submit.");
  return true; // form submits
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form id='form'>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-control-label" for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/QMddPa)

Answer (score 2):

I am writing you a small example.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#control_form").on("keyup", function(event){
        post_control();
    });
});
var post_control = function(){
    var user_name = $("#user_name").val();
  
    if ( user_name==null || user_name=="" || user_name.length < 4 )
        $('.error').html("Username can not be less than 4 characters!");
  
    else
    {
        $('.error').empty();
        $('#control_form').removeAttr('onsubmit');
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="users_form">
    <form name="form" id="control_form" action="post_form" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
        <label>User Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="user_name" name="user_name">
        <input type="submit" value="Save">
    </form>
    <div class="error"></div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

check this it works.I tested it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#form1').submit(function (e) { 

  if($('#name').val() == ''){
     alert('Name is empty');
     return false;
  }

  $(this).submit();
});

});
```